# T, Optional<T> vs. Void, Optional<Void>

Tags: swift

```
// this declaration / definition of variable is OK, as expected
var i = Optional<Int>.None
var j:Int?

// for the next line of code compiler produce a nice warning
// Variable 'v1' inferred to have type 'Optional<Void>' (aka 'Optional<()>'), which may be unexpected
var v1 = Optional<Void>.None

// but the next sentence doesn't produce any warning
var v2:Void?

// nonoptional version produce the warning 'the same way'
// Variable 'v3' inferred to have type '()', which may be unexpected
var v3 = Void()

// but the compiler feels fine with the next
var v4: Void = Void()
```

What is the difference? Why is Swift compiler always happy if the type is anything else than 'Void'  ?

Comment: `v2` is only declared, try assigning it a value and see if the compiler is ok with that

Comment: @Cristic v2 has default value nil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key word in the warning is "inferred." Swift doesn't like inferring `Void` because it's usually not what you meant. But if you explicitly ask for it (`: Void`) then that's fine, and how you would quiet the warning if it's what you mean.

It's important to recognize which types are inferred and which are explicit. To infer is to "deduce or conclude (information) from evidence and reasoning rather than from explicit statements." It is not a synonym for "guess" or "choose." If the type is ambiguous, then the compiler will generate an error. The type must *always* be well-defined. The question is whether it is *explicitly* defined, or defined via *inference* based on explicit information.

This statement has a type inference:

```
let x = Foo()
```

The type of `Foo()` is explicitly known, but the type of `x` is inferred based on the type of the entire expression (`Foo`). It's well defined and completely unambiguous, but it's inferred.

This statement has no type inference:

```
let x: Foo = Foo()
```

But also, there are no type inferences here:

```
var x: Foo? = nil
x = Foo()
```

The type of `x` (`Foo?`) in the second line is explicit because it was explicitly defined in the line above.

That's why some of your examples generate warnings (when there is a `Void` inference) and others do not (when there is only explicit use of `Void`). Why do we care about inferred `Void`? Because it can happen by accident very easily, and is almost never useful. For example:

```
func foo() {}
let x = foo()
```

This is legal Swift, but it generates an "inferred to have type '()'" warning. This is a very easy error to make. You'd like a warning at least if you try to assign the result of something that doesn't return a result.

So how is it possible that we assign the result of something that doesn't return a result? It's because *every* function returns a result. We just are allowed to omit that information if the return is `Void`. It's important to remember that `Void` does not mean "no type" or "nothing." It is just a typealias for `()`, which is a tuple of zero elements. It is just as valid a type as `Int`.

The full form of the above code is:

```
func foo() -> () { return () }
let x = foo()
```

This returns the same warning, because it's the same thing. We're allowed to drop the `-> ()` and the `return ()`, but they exist, and so we could assign `()` to `x` if we wanted to. But it's incredibly unlikely that we'd want to. We almost certainly made a mistake and the compiler warns us about that. If for some reason we *want* this behavior, that's fine. It's legal Swift. We just have to be explicit about the type rather than rely on type inference, and the warning will go away:

```
let x: Void = foo()
```

Swift is being very consistent in generating warnings in your examples, and you really do want those warnings. It's not arbitrary at all.

---

EDIT: You added different example:

```
var v = Optional<Void>()
```

This generates the error: `ambiguous use of 'init()'`. That's because the compiler isn't certain whether you mean `Optional.init()` which would be `.None`, or `Optional.init(_ some: ())`, which would be `.Some(())`. Ambiguous types are forbidden, so you get a hard error.

In Swift any value will implicitly convert with it's equivalent 1-tuple. For example, `1` and `(1)` are different types. The first is an `Int` and the second is a tuple containing an `Int`. But Swift will silently convert between these for you (this is why you sometimes see parentheses pop up in surprising places in error messages). So `foo()` and `foo(())` are the same thing. In almost every possible case, that doesn't matter. But in this one case, where the type really is `()`, that matters and makes things ambiguous.

```
var i = Optional<Int>()
```

This unambiguously refers to `Optional.init()` and returns `nil`.

Comment: I see your point, but Void() or Optional<()>.None on the right side is little bit different from Any. Any() has no sense, just because Any is protocol and can't be instantiated. So in your example x.dynamicType could be different (will be known at run time)

Comment: Rob, please, can you compare this two sentences? var v = Optional<Void>(); var i = Optional<Int>()

Comment: I removed the discussion on `Any`. I had remembered there being special treatment for `Any` and `AnyObject`, but my latest tests indicate that they get treated the same as other protocols. I'm not sure if this was a change in later versions of Swift (I remember a specific warning about `AnyObject` in the early versions of Swift), but it definitely doesn't seem to be true now.

Comment: Thank You very much for Your update!  Especially for its first paragraph. And yes, as you wrote "Swift doesn't like inferring Void because it's usually not what you meant" seems to be true, unfortunately without any real reason. In reality that is not a big issue. My expectation was that compiler should produce the same warning every time or better never, especially if the right side of assignment is very well defined ... Thanks for your time!

Comment: I didn't 'accept' your answer, just in case somebody else would like to join this 'academic' :-) discussion. by the way all of next expressions works fine (but warns you) var (v) = (()); var v0 = Optional<()>(nilLiteral: ()); var v1 = Optional<()>.Some(()); var v2 = (); even though all of them has only one solution.

Comment: Updated. Hopefully I've better explained type inference.

Comment: @user3441734 Possibly the following question can be of interest to you: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34561452/3 (regards the empty tuple)

Comment: @dfri thanks, for possible use of ()? see my notes to Cristic's answer. try? f() , where 'func f() throws () { ... } is the construct ( with relation to .map, .flatMap, .filer and .enumeration() ) which i use in one of my latest swift's experiments. i am pretty familiar with swift concept and i simply don't like, if compiler try to be 'very clever', because normally i try to avoid every single warning.

Comment: Your "throw" example doesn't generate a warning, except that `v` isn't used (which is the correct warning). As suggested, just use `let _ = try?` and it generates no warning. I don't understand what you mean here by "very clever." Do you have an example that actually generates a warning? (If you do use `v` later, it generates no warning at all.)

Comment: yes, try? ... works, the note about 'very clever' is related  to var v = Void()   or var v = Optional<Void>.None So, or so, I learn something very useful. () can be represented as 'nilLiteral', var v = Optional<()>(nilLiteral: ()). I never seen this fact until this discussion begins. var v = Void() // warning, OK, I know ... ; var p: Any = v; p.dynamicType == Int.self  // false; p.dynamicType == Void.self // true; p.dynamicType == ().self   // error: binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Any.Type' (aka 'protocol<>.Type') and '()' It is interesting, isn't it?

Comment: `()` isn't a type here. It's a value (`().self` isn't the type of `()`, it's `()`). What you meant was `p.dynamicType == ().dynamicType`, which is true. As you've seen, you can get to the type of `()` using `Void.self` because `Void` is a typealias, so it is clearly "the type" rather than "the value." All that said, if you're using `Void` very much, you're almost certainly fighting Swift.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is warning you about the "dummy" type `Void`, which is actually an alias for an empty tuple `()`, and which doesn't have too many usages.

If you don't clearly specify that you want your variable to be of type `Void`, and let the compiler infer the type, it will warn you about this, as it might be you didn't wanted to do this in the first place.

For example:

```
func doSomething() -> Void {
}

let a = doSomething()
```

will give you a warning as anyway there's only one possible value `doSomething()` can return - an empty tuple.

On the other hand,

```
let a: Void = doSomething()
```

will not generate a warning as you explicitly tell the compiler that you want a `Void` variable.

Comment: that is the finding, i found the same. why with any other type we don't have a warning? by the way, look at    func f() throws ->Void  and some valuable usage like guard let v = try? f() { print("error thrown by func f()"; return } or if let v = try? f() {} else { print("error thrown by f()" } etc ...